# how to featureUnion numerical and text features in python sklearn properly

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use featureunion for the 1st time in sklearn pipeline to combine numerical (2 columns) and text features (1 column) for multi-class classification.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion

get_text_data = FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x['text'], validate=False)
get_numeric_data = FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x[['num1','num2']], validate=False)

process_and_join_features = FeatureUnion(
         [
            ('numeric_features', Pipeline([
                ('selector', get_numeric_data),
                ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression()))
            ])),
             ('text_features', Pipeline([
                ('selector', get_text_data),
                ('vec', CountVectorizer()),
                ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression()))
            ]))
         ]
    )
```

In this code 'text' is the text columns and 'num1','num2' are 2 numeric column.

The error message is

```
TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform. 'Pipeline(memory=None,
 steps=[('selector', FunctionTransformer(accept_sparse=False,
      func=<function <lambda> at 0x7fefa8efd840>, inv_kw_args=None,
      inverse_func=None, kw_args=None, pass_y='deprecated',
      validate=False)), ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weigh...=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
      verbose=0, warm_start=False),
      n_jobs=1))])' (type <class 'sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline'>) doesn't
```

Any step I missed?

Comment: First, your `'clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression()` should be a third step in the pipeline, not combined in the second step with text. Second, please share some sample data and full stack trace of error. Are you calling fit(), or predict() on pipeline?

Comment: thanks, totally makes sense now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `FeatureUnion` should be used as a step in the pipeline, not around the pipeline. The error you are getting is because you have a Classifier not as the final step - the union tries to call `fit` and `transform` on all transformers and a classifier does not have a `transform` method.

Simply rework to have an outer pipeline with the classifier as the final step:

```
process_and_join_features = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
            ('numeric_features', Pipeline([
                ('selector', get_numeric_data)
            ])),
             ('text_features', Pipeline([
                ('selector', get_text_data),
                ('vec', CountVectorizer())
            ]))
         ])),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression()))
])
```

Also see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html) for a good example on the scikit-learn website doing this sort of thing.

Comment: thank you for your simple and clear explanation! it works now

Comment: If not done so, still read Zac's [blog](http://zacstewart.com/2014/08/05/pipelines-of-featureunions-of-pipelines.html). It helped me to understand pipelines. The flow charts make it quite clear how FeatureUnion and Pipeline work. In fact I now sometimes draw similar ones, if my pipes get too complicated.

Answer (score 6):

While I believe @Ken Syme correctly identified the problem and provided a fix for what you intend to do. However, just in case you actually intend to use the output of the classifier as a feature for a higher level model, check out [this blog](http://zacstewart.com/2014/08/05/pipelines-of-featureunions-of-pipelines.html).

Using the ModelTransformer by Zac, you can have your pipe as follows:

```
class ModelTransformer(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        return DataFrame(self.model.predict(X))


process_and_join_features = FeatureUnion(
         [
            ('numeric_features', Pipeline([
                ('selector', get_numeric_data),
                ('clf', ModelTransformer(OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression())))
            ])),
             ('text_features', Pipeline([
                ('selector', get_text_data),
                ('vec', CountVectorizer()),
                ('clf', ModelTransformer(OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression())))
            ]))
         ]
)
```

Depending on your concrete next steps you still may have to wrap the FeatureUnion in a Pipeline (e.g. using the shortcut [make_pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline)).

Comment: Nice alternative!